# Laravel Form Select Custom Text

Tags: forms, laravel, select

I'm sending list data from my controller:

```
$data['provider'] = CreditType::lists('amount', 'id');
return view('admin.credit.create',$data);
```

and on my view

```
{!! Form::select("amount", $provider, null, ["class"=>"form-control"]) !!}
```

It's work but i want to show the amount with custom text, example

amount table

```
{5000, 10000, 50000}
```

and on select i want to show the amount with custom text and number format

```
ID 5.000
ID 10.000
ID 50.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this way

Do a foreach and construct the form select and then will do `number_format` for the required item

`{{ number_format($provider->price, 2) }}`

**Note :**

1. You shall decide the `.` or `,` for currency
2. Just [concat](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) `ID` in your form select to get `ID 5.000`

If you need to use `Form::select`, then you should first convert your array and then make it done.

**How can i do this ?**

1. In your controller or view do a foreach
2. Append and do number_format
3. Get the new array like $provider_new

And do

```
{!! Form::select("amount", $provider_new, null, ["class"=>"form-control"]) !!}
```

Comment: @yudijohn Updated the answer which allows you to use 'Form::select'

Answer (score 2):

1. Fallback to vanilla blade is always an option:

   ```
   <select>
       @foreach($provider as $key => $number)
       <option name="{{$key}}">{{ number_format($number, 0, '.', ' ') }</option>
       @endforeach
   </select>
   ```
2. As an alternative, you may separate your $provider and do number_format in your controller.
3. And finally, javascript is perfectly able to shoulder the task. Write in comments if you require explanations.

Comment: i can't using Form::select ??

Comment: @yudijohn I updated my answer. And no, you can't force `Form::select` to do that kind of advanced filtering.